# Do Grignard reagents deprotonate amines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, amines

Can I add Mg/dry ether to 2,4,6-tribromoaniline followed by $\ce{D2O}$ in order to replace the bromines with deuterium?

The reaction I'm proposing is part of a synthetic route as shown below.

[image: Overall transformation]

Comment: Amine or amide?

Comment: Amine. The picture shows the conversion to be done, and I'm with TriBromo anilene trying to replace it's Br s with D

Comment: Yes, it will deprotonate tribromoaniline

Comment: you can never use Grignards in presence of acidic protons.

Comment: @gannex Usually true, but if you have an excess of Grignard and the deprotonated species still reacts with the surplus Grignard, you might be able to get away with it. It is a wasteful way to use Grignard reagents, though. And in this case it risks throwing away a lot of the substrate.

Comment: Yes this is true. This seems to be a common reaction with carboxylic acids, but will this also work with amines? I figure it's a question of pKa and whatnot, but I've never read about people doing reactions like that.

Answer (score 5):

If you really wanted to start with the substituted aniline, you could probably oxidize, deuterate, reduce to get the product if you indeed want the amine and not the amide, but the yield would be poor. Various peroxides and peroxybenzoic acids will do this for you. Lui, Li, *et al.* indicated that oxidation of substituted anilines would work best in dichloroethane or THF with 4-5 equivalents of *m*-CPBA, with little difference produced by electronic effects. Then you could use your metal reagent, deuterate, and reduce using a method of your choice.

[image]

Of course it's probably easier to just nitrate your 1,3,5-tribromobenzene directly with nitric acid.

If this is a question from a book, they're probably trying to make sure you notice that you can't use organometal chemistry when you have acidic protons, so yes, grignard reagents do deprotonate amines.

Comment: What about alpha hydrogens? Why don't Grignard reagents deprotonate these acidic protons?

Comment: α-hydrogens are not that acidic (pka = 20-30) and Grignard reagents are strong nucleophiles, so if a carbonyl is present in the molecule, nucleophilic attack will be preferred over proton-abstraction.

Comment: Li would react with nitro-compound even easier than with amine.