# Why is this grignard synthesis incorrect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

[image]

This reaction is mentioned as incorrect in my exercise book. Why is this so? My guess was that the Magnesium, instead of forming a grignard reagent with the compound and bromine, would instead form a complex with the N atom. However, wouldn't the complex formed be quite unstable due to the size of the ligand and the steric hindrance associated with it?

Is this reaction incorrect? If so, what reaction would take place here?

Comment: It is not about complexes at all. Grignard doesn't sit well with acidic protons like N-H.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I knew that it doesn't work with O-H but *comparatively*, just how acidic is the cyclic N-H compared to an O-H bond?

Comment: Much weaker than O-H, but still way too strong to do Grignard anywhere near it.

Comment: Another thing is that your compound wouldn't make particularly bulky ligand.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96881/reaction-of-grignard-reagent-with-primary-amines

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/which-alkyl-halides-can-not-form-grignard-reagent https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49377/do-grignard-reagents-deprotonate-amines

Answer (score 3):

Product would not form as intended, not proceeding in the path of synthesis usually seen with such a sequence of reagents.

This is due to the (quite) acidic hydrogen atom attached to the heteroatom nitrogen in the ring, which would be readily abstracted by the dense electron cloud on the initial Grignard complex that would form.

The species drawn are highly unstable and would have a really short half-life.

[image: grignard reagent fails to remain in synthetically useful form-reaction mech]

The nitrogen could be protonated subsequently. The desired product simply will not form because a reaction much faster than it will consume the formed reagent instantly.

The Grignard reagent fails to remain in a synthetically useful form.

Comment: Your reaction scheme isn't perfect, but, oh well... BTW there's direct reduction of amine hydrogen may be more important reaction then formation and destruction of Grignard reagent.

Comment: Well, it is possible that there are lapses in my knowledge (freshman year chemist here), but I'm not sure if piperidine can be reduced any further.. Even a Google search didn't yield anything useful. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's just like reaction of alcohol with sodium - you get alcoholate and hydrogen.

Comment: @Mithoron Ahh.. makes sense. But is the H that acidic (N is additionally in a ring, not a simple amine)?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer For what it's worth,the H of a aliphatic alcohol isn't that acidic either(considering the high basicity of the RO- anion). So qualitatively speaking,I think I would give the H in the reagent here a pass as well for this reaction

Comment: @Yusuf Well I meant acidic enough for a metal to reduce H to H2 gas. OH is more acidic  than NH, as N- looks like a stronger base than O- (electronegatively speaking). But again, I guess talking these properties is not helping, as the reaction is in heterogeneous phase and in ethereal medium.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer Yeah,I guess both of our answers should be edited with Mithoron's comment to show that this highly simplified picture isn't the complete truth

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to throw in some more perspective here, although your main question has been answered.

First, let's see a postulated mechanism of formation of Grignard reagent in the presence of Mg and diethyl ether.

[image]

[source](http://research.cm.utexas.edu/nbauld/grignard.htm)

The tentative problems that would *may* arise by the presence of the N-H bond would be:

1)The R radical made in the first step might begin a homolysis reaction with  the H of the N-H, and thereby forming a kind of [amino radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_radical) radical. This may lead to further erroneous coupling in the synthesis.

2) Like the answer and comments above state, the **major** reason for the failure of this synthesis is the reaction of the highly basic Grignard reagent with the acidic H after formation.

3) Non-polar solvents like diethyl ether stabilize the Grignard reagent formed like so:

[image]

The N-H bond will have significant polarity due to difference in electronegativities of N and H, so a lot of ether will be expended in stabilizing this bond, so again, it might hinder the formation of the Grignard reagent

Note: This answer is more like food-for-thought on this issue as far as point 1 and 3 are considered, the clear-cut answer is in point 2.

P.S. As pointed out in the commnts by Mithoron, the reaction happens in a heterogenous state, so the mechanism cited above and all these arguments are highly simplified ways of looking at a picture perhaps not completely understood. This reaction probably bears more similarity with that of sodium and an alcohol

Comment: I found the first point quite satisfying. Good answer!

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer And I didn't. There's no atomic Mg in solution and no radical flying around to react.

Comment: @Mithoron I based this answer on the observations given in the quoted article,and the possible side reactions that can occur. From what I saw,I didn't really talk about atomic Mg,but the R• generated does seem like an independent species

Comment: @Mithoron Can you elaborate on the actual intermediates then?

Comment: Reaction is heterogeneous - reagent adsorbs on Mg surface. Br, or in this case probably mostly N, coordinates with surface atoms  and reduction occurs in bound state. Also @WilliamR.Ebenezer

Comment: @Mithoron I see your point..

Comment: @Mithoron Ok,so the article I cited is somewhat wrong or lacking in info I guess?

Comment: It's simplified and schematic, that's unsurprising, because mechanisms of heterogeneous reactions are poorly known. I think nobody knows what exactly happens on the surface there. I personally doubt it's SET.